# System.out with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm googling without success to figure out how to make ANT print `System.out.println/System.out.print` messages in the console. Messages simply don't appear. I haven't found any simple way of doing this. Is there any?

Thanks

Comment: @org-life-java: What logger do you mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`junit`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task `printsummary` attribute has a special setting `withOutAndErr` that:

> is the same as on but also includes
>   the output of the test as written to
>   System.out and System.err.

Comment: +1 Thanks Martin, I did not know `junit task` print behavior could be overridden.  BTW, task doc is here http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Comment: showoutput="Yes" showing the other log statements along with Sysout.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [echo task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html)

```
<echo message="Hello, world"/>
<echo message="Hello, file" file="logfile.txt" />
```

If you want to read the output from a `<java>` task, use the `outputproperty` attribute:

```
<java ... outputproperty="javaoutput" />
<echo message="${javaoutput}" />
```

Comment: This is not acceptable, I need to call `System.out.println()' from my application's code

Comment: Why do you put a `System.out.println` in your JUnit class then??

Comment: OK, couldn't find anything about that, I guess you'll have to find the junit generated output files and read them.

Comment: @romaintaz: I need user who is executing ant task to see some testing internals in console during the build execution

Answer (score 2):

Another cause for not seeing standard output from your program is if you have forked the java process.

This will happen if you are using the [Java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) and have chosen to fork the execution to another VM:

```
<java classname="com.example.MyClass" fork="true">
    ...
</java>
```