# is it possible to see system.out.print(text) in junit reports?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium-webdriver, junit, ant

I am wondering if it is possible to see some assertions ? or some text in junit reports?
e.g file uploaded
i am using ANT for generating report for my junit test.

Thanks in advance your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but please check if solution mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042856/system-out-with-ant) suits your needs.